# By methods of differentiation under the integral sign

Tags: integration

Could this result be proven by methods of differentiation under the integral sign? I only take interest in differentiation way.
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\ln(\tan^2 (ax))}{1+x^2}dx = \pi\ln(\tanh(a))$$

Comment: I tried to differentiate with respect to $a$ and I got an integral that is impossible to evaluate.

Comment: Though this is not what you asked for, but my be hlepful. See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/287852/prove-int-0-infty-frac-ln-tan2-ax1x2dx-pi-ln-tanha/287863#287863) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/285960/improper-integral-with-an-absolute-value)

Comment: $\ln y^2=2\ln y$

Answer (score 0):

Actually using the derivative really simplifies the problem. After that and a simple substitution one obtain:
$$
J'(a) = 4 \int_0^\infty \frac{t}{\sin t} \frac{dt}{t^2+4a^2}
$$
The last integral can be evaluated by means of complex analysis:
$$
J'(a) = \frac{2\pi}{\sinh 2a}
$$

I guess this is what they really wanted in this problem.